# Div closes automatically

Tags: javascript

Click on button sends value to url then should open div. It opens div and automatically div closes. I want to prevent closing div automatically

Button

```
<td><center><button type="button" id="item" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="<?php echo $id ;?>"> <i class="icon-pen"></i></button></center>
</td>
```

Script below works, it pick up values from the table and send it to URL, then open div, but div closes very fast.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(object) {

        var y = $(object).parent("center").parent("td").parent("tr").find(".nr center").text();
        var x = $(object).attr("value");        

        window.location.href = "korpa.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y; 

        document.getElementById('IzmjenaDiv').style.display = "block";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The div closes because you are changing the location, so it's like you refresh the page. If you want to send a request to `korpa.php` without refreshing or changing location, you should use AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, for response. I have solved the problem the other way.